# replace SharePoint 2013 SQL server instance with Availability group

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-farm

I have a  4 server SharePoint farm.

Two Web Front servers FE1, FE2

TWO App servers APP1, APP2

TWO SQL servers SQL1, SQL2 for SQL server Always on.

I need to replace the current SharePoint SQL server instance on SQL1 with SQL server 2012 Availability groups on SQL1 and SQL2.

I have created a AOAG group on AG1 with a listener SQL-L1

1. I have configured Windows fail-over clustering and SQL availability groups.
2. In the  Central admin i have changed the SQL server instance to the availability listener AG1
3. I also configured the SQL Alias name to point the SQL availability group AG1.

Do i need to run the SharePoint Configuration wizard and change the SQL instance to the AG1 availability group.
 Are there any best practices that I am missing or crucial steps that i have forgotten.

I need to configure the Always on with asynchronous mode with Manual failover.

I get an the following errors after setting the SQL Alias to SQL-L1

- > "Unknown SQL Exception 0 occurred. Additional error information from
  >   SQL Server is included below.  Connecting to a mirrored SQL Server
  >   instance using the MultiSubnetFailover connection option is not
  >   supported."
- > Can not connect to configuration database:
  >   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Connecting to a
  >   mirrored SQL Server instance using the MultiSubnetFailover connection
  >   option is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to run the config wizard. We moved the same server in past and follow the same exact steps.

- mark the Dba readonly and move to new sql server.we did this to minimize the down time.
- stop the sharepoint so that all connection stop to old server.
- create sql alias on the sharepoint server point to new server.
- start the sharepoint
- test it

I always recommend to perform these steps in lower farm to test the process.

Check this for more information https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But i get the errors database not supported errors and Unknown SQL exception error . I have modified the question to reflect detailed errors.